# Energy released from forming a black hole?

Tags: energy, black-holes, astrophysics, supernova, stellar-evolution

Gravitational collapse release potential energy, in some cases a huge amount of it. In the case of a black hole, that collapse goes to "infinity" which suggests the release of "infinite" energy. But in physics, infinities generally don't actually exist but, normally denote places where models break down, often in interesting and insightful ways.

So: how much energy is actuality released in the formation of a black hole? Where does it go?

---

Edit: An example of the kind of situation I'm asking about: Say we start with a neutron star and start duping $^{56}Fe$ onto it until it becomes a black hole. Once that happens, inside the event horizon the potential energy starts dropping and converting into something else (kinetic, thermal, etc.). In a simple model this runs all the way to infinity. But I suspect something more interesting happens.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a particle initially at infinity ($U(\infty)=0$) with some kinetic energy ($T(\infty) = T_0$) relative to the black hole, and some internal energy (mass, chemical, rotational, etc) $E_i$.

Suppose a black hole with internal energy $E_b$.

The particle falls towards the black hole. Then the total energy of the black hole + particle system is $E_b+E_i(r)+T(r)+U(r)$.

As the particle approaches the black hole, that total energy is unchanged. $U$ becomes more negative, $T$ becomes more positive, and $E_i$ either stays the same (fundamental particles) or possibly increases because of tidal effects (complex particles).

If we let $E_i(r) = constant$, then $T(r)+U(r) = T_0$ for all $r$, so the energy of the system as the particle approaches the event horizon is

$E_b + E_i + T_0 \ne \infty$

arbitrarily close to the event horizon.

Comment: Ok, but the "collapse to infinity" is all inside the event horizon. I guess I should have explicitly stated that it's the things happening inside the event horizon that I'm wondering about. Also, I'm referring to the initial formation, not the later growth.